# Why is ArrayList's constuctor (ArrayList(int initialCapacity)) calling its super class's default constructor?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, super

In `ArrayList.java`, why is the `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` constructor calling `super()`?

I know it is trying to call its super class's default constructor, i.e `AbstractList()`. But there is absolutely no implementation in `AbstractList()`.

```
protected AbstractList() {
}
```

Anyway, the super class's default constructor will be called in this case.
What is the need to write `super()`?

Comment: A super class constructor must be called, super() if no constructor is specified. Things go on behind the scenes even with an empty constructor. Calling it explicitly probably ment something to the author (e.g. reminded people not to "correct" it to put in annother constructor), not all code is for the computer

Comment: `super()` is called anyways, as you said. I assume it's just a matter of style to call it explicitly.

Comment: Some IDEs (eclipse) with some stylechecking can mark the constructor with a ridiculouse warning icon on not calling super explicitly.

Comment: So its more like a coding convention I can say. No functionality logic behind it though. Thanks all for the inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the `AbstractList` constructor does nothing, doesn't mean that it doesn't have to be called. To be more precise an empty constructor doesn't actually do nothing. The JVM still does things when a constructor is called even if it's empty. You always have to call a constructor when creating objects and each constructor always has to call a superclass constructor first (except `Object` of course).

If you wouldn't write `super()` in the constructor of `ArrayList`, it would still be called implictly by default. Writing it explictly is just considered good style by some developers. Same goes for declaring an empty default constructor, which also would be default. Altough there is a little inconsistency here. If they would have stuck to the same convention I guess it should be

```
protected AbstractList() {
    super();
}
```

Comment: Yes @stonedsquirrel I agree to your point. If they are following a coding standard then protected AbstractList() and protected AbstractCollection() also suppose to contain super(), but currently it does not

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to write it - `super()` is superfluous, but it does no harm.

Good developers (like yourself, from the sound of it) who know the spec will understand that `super()` is called implicitly before any other code in the constructor, if not specified explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for addressing me as a good developer and for your answer also :)